# How to programmatically turn a javascript animation into a youtube video?

Tags: javascript, video, youtube

I am working on a web application that allows the user to create a "movie" which is implemented as javascript-driven animation.  I would like to give the user the ability to post their movie to YouTube.

The user could of course do this by getting some screen-capture software, but I would like to automate the process -- i.e., the user should just be able to authenticate with YouTube, perhaps wait some period of time for the conversion, and then happily have their movie available for all to see on YouTube.

How might I go about converting the javascript animation into a format suitable for uploading to youtube?

Comment: I'm pretty sure that javascript doesn't support any kind of video encoding capabilities so you are probably going to have to send the frames to some web-service to encode them into a youtube compatible file format.

Answer (score 0):

well i dont have a definate answer - but here is how I would go about finding one:
1st update your javascript to send its output to a bitmap or image of some kind. Render each "frame" over time to this image.

Ssave these images somewhere.  Probably png format - I would NOT reccoment using .jpg as a save format.

Then get a hold of some video encoding library/software/etc.  point that to your sequence of images and turn it loose.

once its done, upload the resulting video to youtube using what you have described already.

Comment: it would be much more helpful if you clarify how to actually render the output of each frame in javascript in the first place before trying to assemble the set of frames into one video clip.